# function to read a line on c programming language

Tags: c

On the C book, (second edition page 29), I read the following content:

```
/* getline: read a line into s, return length */

    int getline(char s[], int lim)
        {
            int c, i;
            for(i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
                s[i] = c;
            if(c == '\n') {
                s[i] = c;
                ++i;
            }
            s[i] = '\0';
            return i;
        }

    }
```

My question is: why it is `i<lim-1` but not `i<lim` in the for condition test? (ps: lim is the maximum length of a line)

Question 2: On C, is `EOF` counted as a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Space needs to be reserved for the null-terminator `\0` that is appended to the string at the end of the loop. (This is how strings are modelled in C).
2. EOF is a special value that denotes the end of a file. Note how `getchar()` returns an `int`: this is chiefly so the value of EOF doesn't have to be within the range of a `char`.